# Sharing of host memory between GPU and CPU. Is this implemented and working in 2.80?

Tags: gpu, memory-management

Does anyone know if sharing of host memory between GPU and CPU for rendering has been implemented and/or working in 2.80?

Thanks.

Comment: Out of core rendering is indeed implemented and working in 2.8, it's automatic. Expect to render 20-30% slower though if you cannot fit inside GPU.

Comment: I'm working on a huge scene and I'm still getting Cuda out of memory error.